# Operation Not Supported on Linked Table

Tags: ms-access, vba

When the function below executes '.Append fld' it produces Error 3057.  I suspect that a fully qualified name is needed but the method is escaping me.  The sub calling this function is passing by way of strTableName "tbl_elements" as it should but that is not enough for this function.

I have tried fitting another bit of code that has successfully reached a Linked table.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "ALTER TABLE [" & CurrentDb.TableDefs(strImportHoldingTable).Connect & "].[" & strImportHoldingTable & "] DROP COLUMN romis_tran_id;"
```

Function in question below

```
Public Function CreateAutoNumberField(ByVal strTableName As String, ByVal strFieldName As String) As Boolean

On Error GoTo Err_CreateAutoNumberField

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    Dim tdef As DAO.TableDef

    Set db = Application.CurrentDb
    Set tdef = db.TableDefs(strTableName)
    Set fld = tdef.CreateField(strFieldName, dbLong)
    With fld
        .Attributes = .Attributes Or dbAutoIncrField
    End With
    With tdef.Fields
        .Append fld
        .Refresh
    End With

    CreateAutoNumberField = True

Exit_CreateAutoNumberField:

    Set fld = Nothing
    Set tdef = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Function

Err_CreateAutoNumberField:

    CreateAutoNumberField = False
    With Err
        MsgBox "Error " & .Number & vbCrLf & .description, vbOKOnly Or vbCritical, "CreateAutoNumberField"
    End With
    Resume Exit_CreateAutoNumberField

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of HansUp I resolved the issue of modifying a linked table.  New problem is that the AutoNumber field is not resetting to 1 without Compact and Repair to the back end which I can not do during working hours.

```
Public Function resetAutoNumber(ByVal strTableName As String, ByVal strFieldName As String, ByVal strIndexName As String) As Boolean
On Error GoTo ErrTrap

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim tdef As DAO.TableDef
Dim strDbPath As String

strDbPath = Mid(CurrentDb.TableDefs(strTableName).Connect, 11)

Set db = DBEngine.OpenDatabase(strDbPath)
Set tdef = db.TableDefs(strTableName)
Set fld = tdef.CreateField(strFieldName, dbLong)
Set ind = tdef.CreateIndex(strIndexName)

'clear table
db.Execute "DELETE * FROM " & strTableName
'delete index
tdef.Indexes.Delete strIndexName
'delete field
tdef.Fields.Delete strFieldName
're-create field
    With fld
        .Attributes = .Attributes Or dbAutoIncrField
        .OrdinalPosition = 0
    End With
    With tdef.Fields
        .Append fld
        .Refresh
    End With
'recreate index
ind.Fields.Append ind.CreateField(strIndexName)
tdef.Indexes.Append ind

Set ind = Nothing
Set fld = Nothing
Set tdef = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

ExitHere:
Exit Function
ErrTrap:
MsgBox Err.description
Resume ExitHere

End Function
```